# When is migration appropriate?

Tags: discussion

When is it appropriate to ask a question I've asked before on mathoverflow, but was unable to obtain a satisfactory answer, on mathstackexchange? ([This question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/96412/applications-and-motivation-of-eta-quotient-generators-and-algorithms) for instance.)

Also is there a sense of when it would be beneficial?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the statute of limitations has expired on that question and you should feel free to ask it on m.se **provided** that you include a link to the MO question (and I'd also recommend posting a link to the m.se question at MO).

Questions that don't get closed on MO are, I would think, unlikely to get better answers here than there, but there's no way to know without trying.